# Unpredictable output

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FAQ : Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/faq-undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>   
int main(){
   int myVal = 0;
   printf("%d %d %d\n", ++myVal,myVal,++myVal);
   myVal = 0 ; /*reset*/      
   std::cout<<++myVal<<" "<<myVal<<" "<<++myVal<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I got the output 2 2 2 in both the cases. How could it be 2 2 2? I expected 2 1 1 or 1 1 2

Comment: oh no. not again. search for `sequence point` in SO and you will get your answer

Comment: Duplicate of [FAQ : Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/faq-undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: @Naveen: Thanks. Nowadays I don't like seeing that sequence 'sequence point'

Comment: nobody answered my question. what is sequence point?

Comment: @Leon: you need to click on the link given by @Naveen and you will have plenty for today...

Comment: @Chubsdad you are 100% correct but it might be worth pointing out that someone who is asking this kind of question probably isn't going to think to search for the term `Sequence points`...  perhaps not even `Undefined Behavior`.  Maybe we need a `What is this?  I don't even...` tag :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Hmmm. I C (not C++ :)) your (sequence :) ) point. Thinking of 'sequence points' give me undefined behavior

Comment: Rewrite your program to: _int myVal = 0; int myValA = ++myVal; int myValB = myVal; int myValC =++myVal; printf("%d %d %d\n", myValA, myValB, myValC)_;. As a general policy, assign your values first, then call printf. (This is not very readable, but people have closed your question before I could finish writing.)

Comment: @Moo: You will not get people to search the FAQ extensively before they post here. And with the "what's the result of `i = ++i + i++`?-style questions they will have nothing they could search for except a bunch of special characters that all search engines choke on. OTOH, we now do have an [FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/) for this that's easy to find and can be used to close such questions very quickly. Naceen did just this. I think this is as easy as it gets.

Comment: @Chubsdad: See my reply to Moo-Juice.

Comment: Now __who would vote to re-open such a clear-cut dupe?__

Comment: @sbi: one of the UB trolls who keeps making new accounts to post silly repeats of this question? ;-)

Comment: @R..: Unlikely. IIRC, you need four digits of rep to cast votes on closing/re-opening.

Comment: Sorry, just a bad attempt to add some humor.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-incrementation operator is actually compiled so all calls to it are executed before the expressions calling printf and cout are evaluated.

It's just as if you had:

```
int myVal = 0;
myVal += 1;
myVal += 1;
printf("%d %d %d\n", myVal, myVal, myVal);
```

It could also imagined that compiler optimisations can go as far as using a constant '2' value instead of performing the incrementations at runtime in that case.

edit: diclaimer : this answer is an attempt at explaining what happened specifically in the case of the OP's code, but it really is an example of undefined behaviour, as compilers can do pretty much whatever they want in this situation.

Comment: No downvote, but every answer to this question really should contain the words "undefined behavior"!